# Auto updating of ListActivity when sqlite database changes

Tags: android, sqlite, service, listactivity

I have an android application that has a background service which polls a web service for new information and writes it into a sqlite database for my application.  The Application also has a list activity that displays the data from this sqlite database.

Basically I want the list to auto update while looking at it if new data comes into the sqlite database from the service writing to it. I could just provide a refresh button of sorts but it would be nice if it would auto update.  Is there an easy way to do that?  Should the service just fire an event that the listactivity subscribes to and invalidate the adapter?  Or is there a way for the adapter to be based off of a cursor or something and automatically update when the underlying data changes?  Just trying to architecturally think through this and want the best and most maintainable (and quick to develop) method.  I'm curious if I've missed a possibility that would make this much easier.

By the way, I'm using Mono for Android (company policy, not my choice).

Comment: Reverse ajax perhaps? (I mean poll for updates) (not sure if applicable)

Comment: Further question, is using a service to constantly poll the web-service and update the local sql database the correct method?  We want a persistent notification in the notifications panel while it is running. as well.  Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically I want the list to auto update while looking at it if new
>   data comes into the sqlite database from the service writing to it.

You could implement a dynamically registered `BrodcastReceiver`(in the `onResume` callback), in your `Activity` containing the list, that could listen for a custom broadcast. When this `BroadcastReceiver` receives the custom broadcast you would update the cursor, call notifyDataSetChanged, in other terms, referesh the list. Your `Service` will insert the new values in the database when it receives them and when it finishes that task it could send a broadcast, your custom broadcast to announce interested observers that new data is available. This will trigger the receiver in the `Activity` if the activity is in the foreground.

I don't know `Mono` for Android to give you some code but you should be able to implement something from the above idea.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds about like what I want.  Mono for Android really is basically the same thing, just minor changes.  I have written android apps in java as well so I'm familiar with it.  Just not with using services and updating lists based on their processing.  I'll implement this and then let you know how it goes.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler class to update your list. You can send message to your Activity from your background service when there is new data and update your list in handleMessage() method of Handler class.